# Typescript: Extend/override class type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using typings *for* an external library, from another external library. The typings provided for a few of the classes are not quite sufficient and I'm wondering how to extend/override them.

The typing library's `module.d.ts`:

```
declare module '@library/module' {
    export class SomethingImportant {
        constructor(props?: any);
    }
}
```

I want to update the typing like this (from a typing file I've already got set up in my code):

```
declare module '@library/module' {
    export interface ImportantProps {
        name: string;
        age: number;
    }
    export class SomethingImportant {
        constructor(props?: ImportantProps);
    }
}
```

The interface is exported as I'd expect, but elsewhere in my code, the type of `props` type isn't enforced. I can do `new SomethingImportant({banana: true})` and typescript doesn't complain.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Could you demonstrate this with a web IDE project?  I am having trouble understanding if you are doing declaration merging or providing your own, separate, declaration files and not using the original one.  If you are merging, then the second `class SomethingImportant` should be a duplicate identifier error.  If you are providing a separate file, then how is your code finding the original one in order to allow `any`?  I just can't reproduce what you're seeing easily myself, and without an obvious [mcve] I could only offer weak guesses.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, understood. I'll get an example put together.